# C# "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0" when using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a very strange issue :

I am taking data out of the SQL using a Stored Procedure :

```sql
'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_RECMP_BY_PH_Code]
@PH_Code NVARCHAR(50)
AS

SELECT  Recurrent_PH_MP.Phase_Code AS Phase_Code,
    MP_BGT.FY_Code AS Fiscal_Year,
    MP_BGT.Budget_Type AS Budget_Type,
    MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol AS Currency,  
    ISNULL(dbo.Get_RECEH_Days_BY_PHCode_FYCode(@PH_Code, MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type), 0) AS EH_Days,
    ISNULL(dbo.Get_RECNH_Days_BY_PHCode_FYCode(@PH_Code, MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type), 0) AS NH_Days,
    ISNULL(ROUND(dbo.Get_RECEH_Val_BY_PHCode_FYCode(@PH_Code, MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type),2), 0) AS EH_Previous_Amount,
    ISNULL(ROUND(dbo.Get_RECNH_Val_BY_PHCode_FYCode(@PH_Code, MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type),2), 0) AS NH_Previous_Amount,
    ISNULL(dbo.Get_Exchange_Rate(MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type),0) AS Rate_Used,
    ISNULL(ROUND(dbo.Get_RECEH_Val_BY_PHCode_FYCode(@PH_Code, MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type)/dbo.Get_Exchange_Rate(MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type),2), 0) AS EH_Amount,
    ISNULL(ROUND(dbo.Get_RECNH_Val_BY_PHCode_FYCode(@PH_Code, MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type)/dbo.Get_Exchange_Rate(MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type),2), 0) AS NH_Amount
    FROM Recurrent_PH_MP_Budgets AS MP_BGT INNER JOIN Recurrent_PH_MP
    ON MP_BGT.Recurrent_MP_Code=Recurrent_PH_MP.Recurrent_MP_Code
    WHERE Recurrent_PH_MP.Phase_Code = @PH_Code GROUP BY Recurrent_PH_MP.Phase_Code, MP_BGT.FY_Code, MP_BGT.Currency_Symbol, MP_BGT.Budget_Type;
```

The Function is :

```c#
public DataTable get_RECMP_BY_PH_Code(string PH_Code)
{
    string res = string.Empty;
    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (var conn1 = DBConnectionUtil.Create())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_RECMP_BY_PH_Code", conn1))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PH_Code", PH_Code);
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "RECMP_By_PH");
                    da.Dispose();
                    tb = ds.Tables[0];
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
    }
    return tb;
}
```

When using this in the code :

```c#
DataTable tb_RECMP_Phase = dm.get_RECMP_BY_PH_Code(phase);
int i = 0;
if (tb_RECMP_Phase != null && tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["EH_Days"] != null && tb_MP_Phase.Rows[i]["Fiscal_Year"].ToString() == "FY " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
            phaseData.REC_BT_DAYS += Convert.ToDouble(tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["EH_Days"]);
        if (tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["EH_Amount"] != null && tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["Fiscal_Year"].ToString() == "FY " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
            phaseData.REC_BT_AMOUNT += Convert.ToDouble(tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["EH_Amount"]);
        if (tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["NH_Days"] != null && tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["Fiscal_Year"].ToString() == "FY " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
            phaseData.REC_OTHER_DAYS += Convert.ToDouble(tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["NH_Days"]);
        if (tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["NH_Amount"] != null && tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["Fiscal_Year"].ToString() == "FY " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
            phaseData.REC_OTHER_AMOUNT += Convert.ToDouble(tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[i]["NH_Amount"]);
    }
}
```

I get the error :

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.]
>      System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex) +2003383
>      System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +21
>      AssetMatrix.Default.generateFinancePhasesTable() in C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\Asset Matrix 8\Asset_Matrix_8\AssetMatrix\Default.aspx.cs:317
>      AssetMatrix.Default.BindData() in C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\Asset Matrix 8\Asset_Matrix_8\AssetMatrix\Default.aspx.cs:115
>      AssetMatrix.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\Asset Matrix 8\Asset_Matrix_8\AssetMatrix\Default.aspx.cs:32
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952

**lthough* with the debugger I get values for `tb_RECMP_Phase.Rows[0]`.

Comment: `tb_RECMP_Phase` might be fine, but you are also using `tb_MP_Phase` data table. Did you check it in debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking whether there are rows in `tb_RECMP_Phase`, but I don't see the same check for `tb_MP_Phase`. Since you've nearly eliminated the possibility of zero rows in the one, it's probably the other.

Comment: Yes. That was it. It was only a typo from long hours of coding. Sorry to ask such a silly question and thank you for your time.